# Docker, he commiteado un contenedor para pasarlo a imagen y ahora esta no funciona

Tags: docker

tenia un contenedor que he estado trabajando en el y me interesaba mantener dichos cambios como imagen, hice un `docker commmit` de la imagen, y he borrado el contenedor, ahora intento crear un nuevo contenedor sobre la imagen modificada y no me carga.

Este seria el comando :

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 -v "Carpeta "Carpeta_de_mi_pc:/var/compartido" --name nombreContenedor miImagenNuevaCreadaDesdeContenedor
```

Entonces se me crea , desde **docker desktop** intento iniciarla y se para , como puedo hacer para que se quede encendida

Answer (score 0):

Al arrancar el docker de forma interactiva `-it` se mantiene activo. Ese era el problema